# Specific click counting mechanism in ASP and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, hitcounter

What is a good way to display a click counter in HTML, if you are using a .aspx file that links to a .cs file which obtains headings from a SQL server without using an external text file to keep track by reading in and out? I'd really rather not use javascript because I want to associate it with a specific ID.

Comment: Even if you don't like to use javascript, anything to do with client side has to be better done with client side programming like JS or JQuery. Saving to database or to a file on sever with each click requires unnecessary postback to server resulting in sluggish site.

Comment: You don't have to postback to save to a file or a database. And if a click is already going to a new page, you can't avoid a postback/refresh anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need some sort of persistent storage to keep track over time. So either a text file, or recording each click to a database table.